# CSS syntax for table class

Tags: css

I have a table which toggles row colour using a style

```
<style>
tr:first-child {background-color: #8BC6FD}
tr:nth-child(2n+3) {background-color: #D4E9FC}
</style>
```

Works great, but I want it to only impact one table on a page and I have an external CSS which i want it on rather than putting the style in each page I need it.

So I tried to put it in my CSS page but however I do it it shows errors, currently I have this.

```
table.toggle {
  tr:first-child background-color: #8BC6FD;
  tr:nth-child(2n+3) background-color: #D4E9FC;
}
```

With the idea I can use this at the top of the table I want to use so that it doesn't mess up the other tables on the page.

```
<table class="toggle" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
```

Comment: You want to have a specific set of CSS for just 1 particular table? Is that what you want?

Comment: @gosi123 no, I want a table class in my external CSS page so I can apply it to any table I need to

Comment: I've posted the answer. Your syntax for writing the `nthchild` is wrong. Please take a look at my answer. It should work.

Comment: @gosi123 yes it does work, just waiting until it lets me accept the answer in another minute, thanks

Comment: Glad it has helped you. Thank you for waiting to accept it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so you want a table class `.toggle` in your external style sheet. The reason why it shows error is because your CSS code is wrong. This is how your write it for `nth child`.

Try this:

```css
.toggle tr:first-child {
  background-color: #8BC6FD;
}

.toggle tr:nth-child(2n+3) {
  background-color: #D4E9FC;
}
```

```html
<table class="toggle">
  <tr>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>Text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Do make sure you have your external stylesheet linked in your `<head>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to include the brackets around each background-color property like so;

```
table.toggle {
 tr:first-child{
    background-color: #8BC6FD;
 } 
tr:nth-child(2n+3) {
    background-color: #D4E9FC;
 }
}
```